# Delphi XE3, Indy TCPServer and TCPClient. transmit and receive CRLF control codes

Tags: delphi

I have been helped in a previous post but another issue has come up that I don't know how to deal in a comment.

I need to know how to do WriteLn with a CRLF at the end of the line. I thought I was sending one but believe I am handling it wrong as it does not seem to be going over. Here are the frames for one of the messages.  This is the human readable version of the message that is transformed by replacing the human readable with the actual control codes.

```
<STX>1H|\^~||||||||||P|1|20150724124402<CR><ETX>91<CR><LF>
<STX>2P|1|PP00015906|||Sox^White||19550506||||||<CR><ETX>56<CR><LF>
<STX>3O|1|G-13-00005||^^^CT/GC|R||||||N||||||||||||||O<CR><ETX>23<CR><LF>
<STX>4O|2|G-13-00005||^^^HPV^HPV|R||||||N||||||||||||||O<CR><ETX>F6<CR><LF>
<STX>5L|1|N<CR><ETX>DF<CR><LF>
```

I assume I am probably doing something wrong when I convert the message from human readable "code" to actual control codes.  The control codes in the middle of the frame seem to be going over OK.  It is the  at the end of the frames that may not be going over.

```
          // replace human readable codes with control codes
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<STX>', #2, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<CR>', #13, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<ETX>', #3, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<LF>', #10, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
```

I am using the following code on the client to check for  control codes.

```
      MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn ;

      crlffound := 'False' ;

      if Pos( #13#10, MsgIn) > 0 then
        crlffound := 'True' ;
```

I have included the full code for clarity.

OnConnect code.

```
procedure TTasksForm.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := Indy8BitEncoding ;

  ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz',     now ) +'  OnConnect') ;

  // connected message
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connected');

end;
```

OnDisconnect code.

```
procedure TTasksForm.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

  ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
                                             '  OnDisconnect') ;
end;
```

Here is the OnExecute code.

```
procedure TTasksForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  lastline : String;
  lastcmd :  String ;
  lastbyte : Byte ;
  i : integer ;
  pantherastmframe : string ;
begin

  lastline := '' ;
  lastcmd := '' ;

  lastbyte := (AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte) ;

  if lastbyte = $5 then  //  <ENQ>
  begin

    lastcmd := '<ENQ>' ;

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add( FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
          '  <=  <ENQ>') ;
      end );

    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Byte(6)) ; // <ACK>

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
          '  =>  <ACK>') ;
      end );

    LastPantherByte := lastbyte  ; // <ENQ>

  end

  else

  if lastbyte = $4 then  // <EOT>
  begin

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd  hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
          '  <=  <EOT>') ;
      end );

    // are there messages to transmit
    if ConsolidatedASTMMessagesMemo.Lines.Count > 0 then
    begin

      // turn off panther timer
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          PantherProcessTimer.Enabled := False ;
        end );

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
            '  =>  <ENQ>') ;
        end );

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Byte(5)) ; // <ENQ>

      lastbyte := (AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte) ;

      if lastbyte = $6 then  // <ACK>
      begin

        lastcmd := '<ACK>' ;

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add( FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
              '  <=  <ACK>') ;
          end );

        // transmit frames
        for i := 0 to ConsolidatedASTMMessagesMemo.Lines.Count-1 do
        begin


          pantherastmframe := ConsolidatedASTMMessagesMemo.Lines[i] ;

          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
                '  =>  ' + pantherastmframe) ;
            end );

          // replace human readable codes with control codes
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<STX>', #2, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<CR>', #13, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<ETX>', #3, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;
          pantherastmframe := StringReplace(pantherastmframe, '<LF>', #10, [rfReplaceAll] ) ;

           AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(pantherastmframe) ;

           // wait for <ACK>

           lastbyte := (AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte) ;

           if lastbyte = $6 then  // <ACK>
           begin

             TThread.Synchronize(nil,
               procedure
                 begin
                   ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
                    '  <=  <ACK>') ;
                end );

            end

            else

            if lastbyte = $21 then  // <NAK>
            begin

              TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                  ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add( FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
                    '  <=  <NAK>') ;
                end );

            end ;

        end ;   // transmit frames

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            ServerTrafficMemo.Lines.Add( FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', now) +
              '  <=  <EOT>') ;
          end );

        // tell panther you are done for now
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(#4) ; // <EOT>

        LastPantherByte := lastbyte ; // <EOT>

        ConsolidatedASTMMessagesMemo.Clear ;

      end ;

      // turn on panther timer
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          PantherProcessTimer.Enabled := True ;
        end );

    end ;

  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`WriteLn()` does indeed send a `CRLF` at the end of the specified data.  The real problem is that you are expecting `ReadLn()` to include that `CRLF` in its output, but it actually does not.  `ReadLn()` waits for the specified terminator (`LF` by default) and then strips the terminator from the output (if the terminator used is `LF` and a `CRLF` is received, the entire `CRLF` is stripped). Your code is not accounting for that, eg:

```
MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn + #13#10;
// or, if you do not actually need the CRLF in the output:
// MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn;

// no need for checking Pos()...
crlffound := 'True';
```

Do note that if you set the IOHandler's `ReadTimeout` property, or `ReadLn`'s `ATimeout` parameter, to a non-infinite timeout then `ReadLn()` will return a blank string on timeout and set the `ReadLnTimedOut` property to True, instead of raise an exception:

```
MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn + #13#10;
if PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedOut then
begin
  // do something...
end else
begin
  crlffound := 'True';
  // do something else...
end;
```

Also note that by default, `ReadLn()` handles bare-LF and CRLF equally as a line terminator.  If you want to handle only CRLF specifically, you can specify CRLF in the optional `ATerminator` parameter:

```
ReadLn(#13#10)
```

With all of that said, another option is to use `WaitFor()` instead of `ReadLn()`.  `WaitFor()` has an optional `AInclusive` parameter that you can set to True to include the CRLF in the output.  It will also raise an exception if a read timeout elapses:

```
MsgIn := PantherIdTCPClient.IOHandler.WaitFor(#13#10, True, True);
// no need for Pos() here...
crlffound := 'True';
```

> OnConnect code.
>   OnDisconnect code.

Your event handlers have thread-unsafe code in them.  The event handlers run in a worker thread inside of `TIdTCPServer`, but they are directly accessing the UI, which is not safe.  You **must** synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing `ServerTrafficMemo`, just like you do in your `OnExecute` event handler (though you are not syncing access to `ConsolidatedASTMMessagesMemo`, you **must** do so).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of both ends of that code, and it is the data transfer I think it is, you owe it to yourself to learn RESTful stuff. It will make your code much more flexible and it will give you some strong ability to write cleaner abstraction. That makes for speedier development.